# Как фильтровать определённые теги в TinyMCE (invalid attributes)?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

Например, чтобы вместо

```
<p dir="mso">
```

становилось просто

```
<p>
```

Есть ли параметр в TinyMCE, куда можно добавить invalid attributes? Или как можно подойти к решению этого вопроса?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого надо использовать параметр [extended_valid_elements](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-filtering/#extended_valid_elements). Он предназначен для **переопределения всех правил** для элемента. Для того, тобы запретить присутствие внутри тега `<p>` атрибута `dir` (и вообще всех, кроме, например, `class`), нужно прописать следующее в инициализации TinyMCE:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    extended_valid_elements: 'p[class]'
})
```

Это будет удалять все атрибуты внутри тега `<p>` кроме `class`.